# Is it recommended to face Qiblah while working?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis, qiblah

My father told me to keep a laptop or desktop @Qiblah side & then start working (to get benefits). Are these valid thoughts per Islamic perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned many times in the hadith of the Prophet SAW.

Among the related hadiths, the Prophet SAW said: *"The best ceremony is the one facing the Qibla."* **(Narrated by Al-Tabari in Tahzib al-Athar)**

In another hadith, the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: *"Indeed, for every thing there is glory, and the noblest of ceremonies are those who face the Qibla."* **(Narrated by al-Hakim in al-Mustadrak)**

In addition, in **al-Mausu'ah al-Fiqhiyyah (4/76)** mentions: The fuqaha’ has agreed that the most honoured direction is the Qibla. Thus, it is sunnah to uphold this direction when we are sitting or doing works.

Apart from that, the best Islamic practice that you can do for your IT related or perhaps, any halal job or daily activities in the world is to set the *Ni'at* of your work or things to Allah. Even from the smallest daily thing that you do, always set your ni'at that you do it for Allah so that He may pours His blessings among us.

Wallahualam.